# How to normalize tags table

Tags: php, mysql, database, normalization

I had table like this:

```
post:
+----------------+-----------+
| article_id     | tags      | 
+----------------+-----------+
| 1              |  x1,x2,x3| 
| 2              |  x1,x4,x5 | 
+----------------+-----------+
```

what i am trying to do is to normalize it, so i create 2 more tables:

```
tags:
+----------------+-----------+
| tag_id         | tag_name  | 
+----------------+-----------+
| 1              |    x1     | 
| 2              |    x2     | 
| 3              |    x3     |
+----------------+-----------+

post_tag:
+----------------+-----------+
| id_post         | id_tag  | 
+----------------+-----------+
| 1              |    1     | 
| 1              |    2     | 
| 2              |    1     |
+----------------+-----------+
```

I have exported all tags from post table to tags table and now each tag has his own id in tags table, but I am so confused when i am thinking how to do it with post_tag table?

edit: questin is how to populate post_tag table, how the query would look like?

tried like this

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM post"); 
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $article_id=$row['article_id'];
  $all_tags =$row['tags'];      
  $tags= explode(",",$all_tags);                                
    foreach($all_tags as $tag) {
     $sql2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag_name = '$tag'");
      while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) {                               $tag_id=$row['tag_id'];                                  $q = "INSERT INTO post_tag (id_post, id_tag) VALUE ('$article_id', $tag_id')";
        $r = mysql_query($q);
      }
    }
}
```

but it doesn't write complete post_tag table

Comment: This seems fine .. what are you confused about?

Comment: what's your problem? The post_tag table is fine

Comment: What you have is a *n to n* relation between posts and tags. Your post_tag table entries will act as links between one tag and one post. Like this you will link one post to n tags, and one tag to n posts.

Comment: @Eregrith: it's more common to use M and N, different letters

Comment: What I meant is the relation is `0,n` on each side.

Comment: how to do it, I do not know how to populate (related) post_tag table.

Comment: I'm trying to answer your question about how to populate the post_tag table from your existing data. Please clarify the structure of the original 'post' table. As best I can tell, the 'article_id' field corresponds to 'post_tag.id_post'. There are multiple tags stored in one row of the 'post' table, but it isn't clear to me how they are stored. Do you have a fixed number of tag fields, each either with NULL or a tag name as a string? Do you have a single text field with a comma separated string of tags? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this one will work?

```
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM post"); 
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $article_id=$row['article_id'];
    $all_tags = $row['tags'];      
    $tags = explode(",",$all_tags);              
    foreach($all_tags as $tag_title) {
        $tag_id = null;
        $tag=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query('SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag_name = "'.$tag_title.'"'));
        if ($tag) {
            $tag_id = $tag['tag_id']; 
        } else {
            mysql_query('INSERT INTO tags SET tag_name = "'.$tag_title.'"');
            $tag_id = mysql_insert_id();
        } 
        $q = "INSERT INTO post_tag (id_post, id_tag) VALUE ('$article_id', $tag_id')";
        $r = mysql_query($q);
    }
}
```

After running the loop, you will need to drop the old column in `post` table

Answer (score 1):

For every tag a post has, you insert an entry in the post_tag table. It's called an m-to-n relationship. Google it ;)

- post_id: 1, tag_id: 1
- post_id: 1, tag_id: 2
- post_id: 1, tag_id: 3

post

- post_id

tag

- tag_id
- tag_name

post_tag

- post_id
- tag_id

Answer (score 1):

I see, you want to solve your issue with one sql-query, but it's not convenient. Try to use php-power and you'll succeed.

The php way.
1. Create tables `tags` and `posts_tags` (like you described in the question).
2. In php get all rows from your current `post` table and loop it:

```
foreach($query_results as $row) {
  $article_id = $row['article_id];
  $tags = explode('|', $row['tags']);
  foreach($tags as $tag) {
    // here check if this tag exists in your new `tags` table (by tag's name). If it is, save its id in $tag_id variable.
    // if a tag don't exists then insert it. And put its new id (mysql returns it after inserting) into $tag_id.
    // After that add a row ($article_id, $tag_id) to table `posts_tags`
  }
}
```

Then delete column `tags` from old `post` table. Profit!

p.s. Create unique indexes on tag's name in `tags` table and on pair (article_id, tag_id) in `posts_tags` table.

Comment: the part you "described" is exactly what makes me confused, it's loop inside loop, inside loop,...

Comment: There are just two loops here. It's alright. And take attention that in this case the optimization isn't needed, because you do that operation (re-making a database) once.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a post called `my cat!`, and it has an id of `1`. You wish to add the tags `cats` and `home` to it.

You should first create the tags `cats` and `home` in the tags table, if they don't already exist. lets say they are `cats | 2` and `home | 4` (the number is their id).

You then need to store in the post_tag table the values `1 | 2` and `1 | 4`, where the first value is the post's id, and the second value is the tag's id.

To find tags for post number 1, you'd want something like

`SELECT Tags.name FROM Tags, Tags_Posts WHERE Tags_Posts.post_id = 1 AND Tags.id = Tags_Posts.tag_id`

Comment: that's all clear, I got it, but I am confused how to do it with existing database, how mysql query should look like... how to populate post_tag table?

Comment: thank you Ivo, but i am trying to populate post_tag table from existing   post, tag tables

Comment: As I said, populate the tags table first, then insert values into the join table which link up tag ids with post ids.

Comment: i don't get it, how would the query look like?

Comment: You issue two `INSERT` queries, the second depending on the outcome of the first (it needs the `id`).